# Thread-safe triangulation library

Tags: c++, thread-safety, triangulation

I'm writing a C++ software which needs fast [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) computations. An implementation based on double suffices.

I evaluated some geometric libraries such as

- [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/)
- [LEDA](http://www.algorithmic-solutions.com/leda/)
- [boost::geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html) (doesn't have the Minkowski sum implementation, but there is a [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/polygon/doc/gtl_minkowski_tutorial.htm) explaining how to implement it)

but I ended up using another third-party library which is very fast compared to the previous ones and which uses the [FIST](http://www.cosy.sbg.ac.at/~held/projects/triang/triang.html) library for triangulation.

My code works more or less in the following way:

- I read my polygons
- I compute the Minkowski sums I need
- For n times

  - I decide which polygons to use in the following computation
  - I do some stuff based on the Minkowski sums
  - I give a value to the result
- I take the result with the best value as the final result

Since the computations within the loop are independent from round to round, I parallelized the loop and everything worked fine.

Then I decided to move the Minkowski sum computation in each parallel round:

- I read my polygons
- For number_of_threads(=n) times

  - I decide which polygons to use in the following computation
  - I compute the Minkowski sums I need in this round
  - I do some stuff based on the Minkowski sums
  - I give a value to the result
- I take the result with the best value as the final result

but the third-party library worked no more.

I get `number_of_threads - 1` error messages saying

> Assertion Failed.

The files causing the assertion failure change from run to run and from thread to thread, but they all are c-files having same name as the FIST headers (while I have the source code of the third-party library, I have only a .lib and the headers of the FIST library)

As stated before, I tried to compute all the Minkowski sums I need outside the parallelized code and use the results within it. This was ok. So I'm almost sure that the problems come from FIST.

I have two questions:

- Do you know if the [FIST](http://www.cosy.sbg.ac.at/~held/projects/triang/triang.html) library is thread safe?
- If not, could you please suggest me a thread-safe (C or, better,) C++ triangulation library to replace FIST (possibly with comparable performances)?

**edit:**

Actually, I don't know if "thread-safe" is exactly what I want: I only need a tringulation library able to compute many independent triangulations at the same time.

I think that if the library had not global variables and if it had a class without `static` variables

```
class triangulation
{
    // no static variables

    void execute_triangulation();
}
```

it could be enough.
So I could use different instances of that class and run in parallel their method.

Comment: In general, if not explicitly specified to be thread safe you might want to consider everything as _not_ thread safe.

Comment: It is not clear if this is due to the thread safety of your library or a mistake in your code. It is not clear if you should worry about thread safety.

Comment: @Mikhail You are right, I'll edit my question

Comment: You said you chose FIST because it is faster. Are you talking about the Minkowski sum, the triangulation or both?

Comment: @sloriot Sorry if my explanation isn't clear. I need Minkowski sum, but the third-party library for Minkowski sum computation I chose, calls the FIST library. Since I have the source code, I can replace the FIST library with another triangulation library.

Comment: OK, I don't know about FIST, but AFAIK, you can have several instances of CGAL triangulations is different threads

Comment: You explain a lot of what you do and how you do it, but you don't actually show the code; if you expect a help with code, give us some snippets to work with

Comment: You may want to add your licensing requirements to the question: apparently you want something free but not GPL, so BSD-like I assume.

Comment: Well, the easiest way around your thread-safety issues could be to not use threads -- use several processes instead. If you know roughly in advance how to split the tasks between the processes, you will need very little communication between the processes.

Comment: @MarcGlisse If the license was BSD-like it would be wonderful! Otherwise I need a (not too expensive!) commercial license.

Comment: @888 What you require is the basic thread safety guarantee, which should be granted with e.g. CGAL...

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use the [2D triangulation package of CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_2/Chapter_main.html) to replace FIST, and then use it as the input of that third-party library that does Minskowski sums. The CGAL triangulations are very fast, and reliable. You can triangulate polygons and complex shapes using constrained Delaunay triangulation.

By the way, which Minkowsky library do you use?

Comment: I know that the 2D triangulation package of CGAL can use all kind of kernel (which is good for me, since I don't need an "exact" one), but I'm probably excluding it beacause the commercial license is quite expensive for us. I'm sorry, but my boss prefer to keep secret the library we are using.

Answer (score 2):

One possible and immediately testable solution is to place a mutex around the code that invokes the Minkowski calculations. If that sounds interesting and you don't know how to do it, add a comment detailing the platform you're using and I, or someone else, will outline how to do it.

At the very least, that will show you whether you have correctly identified the problem. If the calculations form a small part of your total bandwidth, then it may turn out to be a good solution - otherwise just a step on the road.

Answer (score 1):

It depends very heavily on what you mean by this:

> Since my code is parallelizable I introduced multithreading

You need to be more specific in order to get help. What does it mean "you have introduced multithreading"? For example, none of the libraries you mention have parallel computation of Minkowski sums (or anything else) built in - you will need to parallelize it yourself.

With regard to Minkowski sums, it is possible to use a map-reduce approach: split the input data set into smaller parts, compute Minkowski sum for each in parallel (map) and union the intermediate results as they come in from independent workers (reduce). The requirements for this are a basic thread safety guarantee (which e.g. CGAL gives you) with read only access to the parameters of the computation.